# Can you export deck composition to a text format?

Tags: scrolls

Is it possible to export you card collection and deck composition into text format?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to do this.  I'm going to do a bit of reverse-engineering and packet sniffing on this.  Maybe I can write a tool to pull this info from their system.  I am, however, doubtful that I'll be able to do this without doing something that may break the TOS.

Comment: Further comment... it looks like much of scrolls is built on top of IRC.  I didn't discover this by the aforementioned packet-sniffing but by other research into scrolls.  Later, when I get the chance, I'll see if I can tap into an IRC channel and make some calls to a system bot and see if it can return this data in an easily consumable manner.

Comment: Do you mean that there is nothing saved locally on the PC but it is all retrieved from their servers?

Comment: Drake: There is some binary data that I was able to find on the windows and mac variations that is stored in user folders.  I haven't compared the two sets of files yet, but it doesn't look like this information is dynamic.  It's more a bunch of static information to the user's experience or, one-time loaded data that is specific to your user account.

Answer (score 1):

I'll update my response when we get additional information that's a bit more official.

In the mean time, according to the Scrolls Guide pseudo-official Scrolls Blog there is a mod update in the works for "a few weeks from now", which will hopefully translate into mid-July update.

From the [very coy blog post](http://www.scrollsguide.com/news/1560/scrolls-modloader-spoiler), it looks like there will be a deck importation feature, as well as a previous match summary report.  Hopefully if there is a deck importer, there is a deck exporter.

Knowing Mojang's track record and general friendliness to the external dev community, I'd reasonably speculate that if an export function exists, it will be in a text-readable format and will most likely be XML.

**UPDATE**

Summoner, the unofficial mod-loader from Scrolls Guide is out.  ([Get it here.](http://www.scrollsguide.com/summoner))  This mod allows for the import and export of deck information and is available for Windows and OS X.